# Inline assembler doesn't work well, error: double free or corruption (!prev)

Tags: c, assembly

I have one simple problem. Inline assembler isn't working well. First, the last row in 2d array is omitted (I checked it).  Therefore I have one error "double free or corruption (!prev): 0x087d7200 ***". I use AT&T syntax. 32 bit

```
#define SIZE2 500
```

### Create Array

```
 int **dane2 = (int**)malloc(SIZE2 * sizeof(int*));
int i;
for(i=0;i<SIZE2;i++)
{
    dane2[i]=(int*) malloc(SIZE2 * sizeof(int));
}
```

### Function where I use assembler

```
    void dodaj2(int **dane2)
{
int size;
size = SIZE2;
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<SIZE2;++i)
{
    for(j=0;j<SIZE2;++j)
    {
    //  dane2[i][j] = dane2[i][j]*3 + dane2[i][j] + dane2[i][j]/2 +dane2[i][j]*4;
        asm volatile ( 
        "xor %%eax,%%eax \n\
        xor %%edx, %%edx \n\
        movl %%esi, %%eax \n\
        movl %%edi, %%esi \n\
        mull %%esi \n\
        addl %%ecx, %%eax \n\
        movl (%%ebx,%%eax,4), %%edi \n\
        #int3 \n\
        movl %%edi, %%edx \n\
        shl $3, %%edi \n\
        shr $1, %%edx \n\
        addl %%edx, %%edi \n\
        movl %%edi, (%%ebx, %%eax,4) \n\
        #int3"
        :
        :"S"(i), "c"(j), "b"(*dane2), "D"(size)
        );
    }
}

}
```

The inline assembler should work like this line:

```
//dane2[i][j] = dane2[i][j]*3 + dane2[i][j] + dane2[i][j]/2 + dane2[i][j]*4;
```

I calculated the address of the element based on the model

```
dane2(i*(amonut of rows) + j) * 4
```

### Free memory.

```
int k;
for(k=0;k<SIZE2;k++)
{
    free(dane2[k]);
}
free(dane2);
```

I don't know where the mistake is.

Comment: You modify registers without telling the compiler. You should use output constraints and clobbers properly.I hope this is some sort of school assignment, because otherwise this inline asm makes no sense.

Comment: Do **not** cast malloc. `int **dane2 = (int**)malloc(SIZE2 * sizeof(int*));` should be `int **dane2 = malloc (SIZE2 * sizeof *dane2);` and `dane2[i]=(int*) malloc(SIZE2 * sizeof(int));` should be `dane2[i] = malloc (SIZE2 * sizeof **dane2);`

Comment: Read [Brennan's Guide to Inline Assembly](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/brennan/brennan_att_inline_djgpp.html) - specifically the part about clobbered registers.

Comment: In your `free` you can check against a double free with `if (dane2[k]) free(dane2[k]);` This isn't a long term fix, but it is a quick test to see if something in your handling of the calling convention is causing an alteration to addresses within `dane2`, etc..